# Why StringBuilder acting like pass by reference

Tags: java, stringbuilder

check this code

```
   public class StringbuilderDoubt {

    public static void main(String args[]){
           new StringbuilderDoubt().methodTest();
    }

    public void methodTest(){
        String str=new String("Default");
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        sB1(str,sb);
        sB2(str,sb);
        System.out.println(str+".........."+sb);
    }
    private void sB1(String str1, StringBuilder sb1){
                    str1+="str1";
                    sb1.append("sB1");
    }

    private void sB2(String str2, StringBuilder sb2){
        str2+="str2";
        sb2.append("sB2");
    }
}
```

Output is: `Default..........sB1sB2`
Why StringBuilder is working like pass by reference?
In methodTest I am passing two objects string and string builder. String is pass by value but StringBuilder looks like pass by refence and StringBuilder  object from calling method getting changed.

Comment: strings are immutable.

Comment: You are passing a reference to an instance of the StringBuilder class _by value_. Java always uses pass-by-value semantics. The fact that you can modify the object to which you are passed a reference has nothing to do with pass-by-value versus pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you pass a StringBuilder instance to a method, the instance value is passed by value.  As you've seen, you can append characters to the StringBuilder instance inside of the method without returning the instance value.

You can also return the StringBuilder instance value if you want, but it's not necessary.  It hasn't changed.

This "pass by reference" also works for most of the Collection classes (List, Map), and for your own classes that have getters and setters.

If you don't want this behavior, you have to make deep copies of the instances you pass.  You would do this if you return a Collection class from a public API.

Comment: Yes. all the collection and form values (setters and getter) are getting changed.

Comment: You can pass StringBuilder to the method and any characters added to it will be there after the method returns. Same about collections. And I do not know how getters and setter are relevant here. It may be other reasons to avoid direct access to public fields but you can assign them for the passed object no problem and the assigned values persist after the method call returns.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see anything wrong with `StringBuilder` here.

Nothing happens to the string referred to by the `str` reference.  In your `sB1` method, you have a local reference `str1`.  The "+=" operator returns a new String, but the original string, being immutable, is not changed.  The same thing happens in your `sB2` method.

So, your variable `str` still contains only "Default".

Comment: Yes. all the collection and form values (setters and getter) are getting changed.
But what I am confusing is , this is violating Pass by value.
objects are pass by reference but when I am passing String or Integer object its not getting changed.
Checked with Integer i1 = new Integer("20");

Comment: Your string "str" is being passed by reference.  But in your "sB1" method, your local "str1" reference is a second reference.  Initially it still refers to the string "Default".  But when the statement "str1+="str1";" is executed, a new string is created, and the reference "str1" now refers to this new string "Defaultstr1".  But this whole time, your "str" variable still refers to the original string, "Default".

Answer (score 1):

Because it **is** passed by reference. The *reference* to the `StringBuilder` is passed by value. You can add characters and they will be in the instance after the method returns. Same way you can pass a Collection and add values inside the invoke method - these will be preserved. You can also call setters or assign public fields, such changes will also persist after return.

The reference to `String` is also passed by value so assigning a new value to this reference has no effect after the method returns.